# Changing value of a global variable using lamda?

Tags: python, lambda

Can we use lambda to change value of a global variable?
Like

```
    lambda ty:ty-=10
```

`ty` being a global variable

Code(sorry for improper indentation):

```
          col = {1:lambda : ty -= 10,
2:lambda:ty -=20 , 
lambda ty:ty-=30}
      col.get(collision,pp)()
```

Comment: Please provide your code, along with error and your expected result

See [How do I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
ty = 10

fn = lambda: globals().update(ty=ty-10)

fn()
print(ty)
```

Prints:

```
0
```

But *don't* do it, it's not very readable and mantainable. I would rather change your example from the question:

```
col = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30}    
ty -= col.get(collision,pp)
```